# Вопрос по MySQL+ php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с сообщениями. Как сделать правильный запрос, чтобы выводило последние 3 сообщения к указанному `id`, но вывод должен быть именно `ORDER BY id ASC`? То есть `$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM an_ask_message WHERE aid = '".intval($id)."' AND del = '0' ORDER BY id ASC");`
Пусть `$id = 3`, тогда в таблице с данными `aid = 3` есть 7 строк, имеющие `id - 2` - 8 и т.п.

Код:

```
<?
$id = $_GET['id'];
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_msg WHERE `aid` = '".intval($id)."' AND del = '0' ORDER BY id ASC");

# Выведем комментарии
$i = 1;
while($taql = mysql_fetch_array($comments)){
  $comment .=($taql['reply'] == 0 ? nl2br($taql['msg']) : '');
  $i++;
}
 echo $comment;
?>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы выводило только последние 3 строки, а не все!?

Comment: `LIMIT 3` не подходит? Можно изменить `ORDER BY`, поставить `LIMIT`, а потом в `php` обрабатывать данные в обратно м порядке.

Comment: @cyadvert, поставив LIMIT 3, мы выведем только 1-ые 3 строки, а мне нужно, чтобы конкретно 3 последние строки вывело, но в том порядке, как они занесены в базу... То есть, имеем строки; test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, нужно чтобы вывело: test3, test4, test5

Comment: да, я понимаю. Но если сдеать `ORER BY id DESC`, а потом в обратном порядке обрабатывать? не получится то, что Вам надо?

Comment: Но как сделать, это подобие в обратном порядке? Тогда вот такой вопрос...

Comment: Можете сделать ваш запрос подзапросом `SELECT * FROM (здесь ваш запрос c LIMIT ORDER BY id DESC) ORDER BY id ASC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно изменить `ORDER BY`, добавить `LIMIT`, а потом в `php` обрабатывать данные в обратном порядке.

Примерно так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM an_ask_message WHERE aid = '".intval($id)."' AND del = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
// переводим результат запроса в массив
$comments = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $comments[] = $row;
}
// переворачиваем массив с ног на голову :)
$comments = array_reverse($comments); 

// и выводим
foreach($comments as $row) {
    echo ($row['reply'] == 0 ? nl2br($row['msg']) : '');
}
```

Comment: Ваш пример не помог, строки как выводились в обратном порядке, так и выводятся...

Comment: ну тогда код вывода строк в студию :) Вопрос исправьте - добавьте php код вывода строк их `$comments`

Comment: Вроде-бы нашёл решение, м.б и туповатое, но работает... `$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM an_ask_message  WHERE aid = '".intval($id)."' AND del = '0' ORDER BY id ASC".($count[0] > 3 ? " LIMIT ".ceil($count[0] - 2).", 3" : ""));` - `$count[0]` считываем кол-во строк, отнимаем 2 и выводим 3, но мне кажется, это бред... Сейчас добавлю полностью код

Comment: но это значит, что сначала надо сделать отдельный запрос только чтобы узнать `$count`?... Не самый лучший вариант :)

Comment: Да знаю, что это бред, код добавил в описание вопроса.

Comment: Обновил, теперь вообще ересть выводит, типо 0, 1, вместо текста

Comment: Всё, работает, спасибо вам